# Insert an item in an array inside a structure - pointer issues?

Tags: c, pointers

This is a header file in my current project where I define two structs:

```
typedef struct{
        unsigned char length;
        unsigned char buffer[8];
        unsigned char index;
    } buffer;

typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned char * SFR;
    unsigned char risingEdges;
    unsigned char fallingEdges;
    unsigned char buffer[2]; 
    buffer * b;
}port;
```

Now when i call this method, the current value of the special function register (by using the SFR pointer in the struct) be inserted in the buffer * b.

```
void portUpdate(port p){
    bufferInsertItem(*p.SFR,*p.b);
    **** More C code omitted 
}
```

This is the implementation of bufferInsertItem

```
void bufferInsertItem(char i,buffer b){
    b.buffer[b.index]=i;
    b.index = b.index++%b.length;
}
```

I'm not really sure and I can't test this embedded project at this moment, but should i really dereference the buffer when i call. I'm a bit confused, also because the name of an array is already a pointer to the first element. So what's really the value of `*p.b`?

```
bufferInsertItem(*p.SFR,*p.b);
```

I'm quite sure that *p.SFR is the actual value of the special function register, but is *p.b the value of the first element in the buffer or the buffer?

Comment: You pass the `port` argument *by value* to `portUpdate`. That means its value is *copied* and inside the function you only work with the copy, not the original. So all changes you make to `p` inside the function will never be seen in the original structure you pass when calling `portUpdate`.

Comment: Regarding your problem, remember that for any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. Now going backward from `*p.b` that is equal to `*(p.b + 0)` which then is equal to `p.b[0]`. So `*p.b` is really `p.b[0]`.

Comment: So my function prototype should be `void portUpdate(port *  p)`? 
If i understand your explanation I should call then `bufferInsertItem(**p.SFR,*p.b)`?

Comment: And should i change `void bufferInsertItem(char i,buffer b)` into void `bufferInsertItem(char i,buffer * b)`?

Comment: Yes you should use a pointer for the `portUpdate` argument. No you should not do double-dereference of `p.b` (because `**p.b` is `**(p.b)`). Instead do `*p->b`.

Comment: There's lots of problems with this code not related to the question. You shouldn't be passing these structs by value. Also you use "sloppy typing" with `unsigned char` sometimes and `char` some other times. Never use `char` for anything else but holding characters - don't use it to hold raw binary values. I would strongly recommend to post the complete code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

With the code shown in the question, the second parameter to `bufferInsertItem` is `buffer b`, meaning it is a `buffer`.

In the call `bufferInsertItem(*p.SFR, *p.b)`, `p` is a `port`, and its `b` member is `buffer *`, that is, a pointer to a `buffer`. Thus `*p.b` is a `buffer`, and that is what should be passed to `bufferInsertItem` given its current definition.

However, that is not likely the desired solution. With its current definition, `bufferInsertItem` receives the **value** of a `buffer`. That is, it receives a copy. Its name suggests it is intended to change the buffer, but it will only be able to change the copy, which will not create any change in the original. To fix this, the parameter type should be changed to `buffer *b`, so that a pointer is passed. Corresponding changes inside `bufferInsertItem` will be needed to use `b` as a pointer rather than as a structure, and the call should then pass `p.b`, not `*p.b`.

In comments, it was stated that the declaration `void portUpdate(port p)` should be changed to `void portUpdate(port *p)`, but this is not necessary to make `bufferInsertItem` work. When `portUpdate` is passed a copy of `p`, that copy includes the member `buffer *b`, which is a pointer to the original `buffer`, and so that original buffer would be modified by the call `bufferInsertItem(*p.SFR, p.b)`. However, structures are often passed by address even when pass by value would work, as a matter of efficiency (less space is used to pass a single address than to pass an entire structure). So `void portUpdate(port p)` could be modified to `void portUpdate(port *p)`, with corresponding changes in other code.

There is no array involved in the use of `buffer`, so it is unclear why the question asks about arrays. It is possible memory for an array of `buffer` could have been allocated, and `p.b` was set to point to the first `buffer` of that array. Nonetheless, the parameter `buffer b` must be given an argument that is a `buffer`, not a pointer to a buffer.